# K nearest elements

Tags: arrays, data-structures, tree, heap

This is an interview question.

There are billions and billions of stars in the universe. Which data structure would you use to answer the query 
"Give me the k stars nearest to Earth".

I thought of heaps. As we can do heapify in O(n) and get the n_smallest in O(logn). Is there a better data structure suited for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input could not be all stored in memory at the same time (that would be a challenge!), but would be a *stream* of the stars in the universe -- like you would get an iterator or something -- you could benefit from using a Max Heap (instead of a Min Heap which might come to mind first).

At the start you would just push the stars in the heap, keyed by their distance to earth, until your heap has *k* entries.

From then on, you ignore any new star when it has a greater distance than the root of your heap. When it is closer than the root-star, substitute the root with that new star and sift it down to restore the heap property.

Your heap will not grow greater than *k* elements, and at all times it will consist of the *k* closest stars among those you have processed.

Some remarks:

- Since it is a Max Heap, you don't know which is the *closest* star (in constant time). When you would stop the algorithm and then pull out the root node one after the other, you would get the *k* closest stars in order of descending distance.
- As the observable(!) Universe has an estimated 10<sup>21</sup> number of stars, you would need one of the best supercomputers ([1 exaFLOPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS)) to hope to process all those stars in a reasonable time. But at least this algorithm only needs to keep *k* stars in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you're going to run into is scale. There are somewhere between 100 billion and 400 billion stars in the Milky Way galaxy alone. There is an estimated 10 billion galaxies. If we assume an average of 100 billion stars per galaxy, that's 10^19 stars in the universe. It's unlikely you'll have the memory for that. And even if you did have enough memory, you probably don't have the time. Assuming your heapify operation could do a billion iterations per second, it would take a trillion seconds (31,700 years). And then you have to add the time it would take to remove the k smallest from the heap.

It's unlikely that you could get a significant improvement by using multiple threads or processes to build the heap.

The key here will be to pre-process the data and store it in a form that lets you quickly eliminate the majority of possibilities. The easiest way would be to have a sorted list of stars, ordered by their distance from Earth. So Sol would be at the top of the list, Proxima Centauri would be next, etc. Then, getting the nearest k stars would be an O(k) operation: just read the top k items from the list.

A sorted list would be pretty hard to update, though. A better alternative would be a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). It's easier to update, and getting the k nearest neighbors is still reasonably quick.